# The computer does not seem to find all my RAM. Can I fix it?

Tags: windows-10, memory

My computer does not seem to detect all my RAM, but it is still listed. Take a look at this screenshot:

[image: screenshot of task manager performance tab]

The title of the diagram says I have 16.0 GB DDR, but the top of the y-axis just shows 8.0 GB. Then it just says 8.0 GB to the left as well, on the memory tab.

If I check the resource monitor, it says my total memory is 8183 MB, but installed is 163584 MB.

I'm hitting the 8GB ceiling all the time now, is there anything I can do? Restarting does not help...

Comment: Have you tried the steps in this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/978610/the-usable-memory-may-be-less-than-the-installed-memory-on-windows-7-b ? Although it is for Windows 7 most of it still applies

Comment: Regarding the article, I have not updated my BIOS yet. I might try that later. The other things did not help.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. You are right. When I check the resource monitor, I have 8 GB as hardware reserved. How annoying. I hope it's not broken.

Comment: Likely it's one of the answers in the duplicate SuperUser question, i.e. BIOS needs updating,  *Maximum Memory* in msconfig is wrong or your motherboard simply doesn't support that memory configuration.

Comment: I't not the maximum memory setting, checked that. Managed to find the new BIOS version now, so that will be my next attempt. It IS an old computer, but I thought I could keep it couple of years longer. We'll see.
Thanks for the help!